# Convert a XML to another XML

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I am very new in XSLT

I have a input xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:LookupRecords xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core" xmlns:urn="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService">
<urn:query>
<a:Headers>
<a:SearchHeader>
<a:SearchHeader>
<a:SearchHeader>
</a:Headers>
<a:Params>
<arr:KeyValueOfguidArrayOfQueryParametertmL6yAXy>
</a:Params>
</urn:query>
</urn:LookupRecords>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the output XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<GetRecordResponse xmlns="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService">
<GetRecordResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core">
<a:Exception i:nil="true"/>
<a:ResponseHeaders>
<a:SearchResults>
<a:StatusCode>Success</a:StatusCode>
<a:StatusCodeReason i:nil="true"/>
</GetRecordResult>
</GetRecordResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now I am trying to change convert this using XSLT such as

```
<s:Envelope>
<xsl:attribute name="xmlns:s"><xsl:value-of select="xmlns:soapenv"/></xsl:attribute>
<s:Body>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

but getting a error "Not well formed: The prefix "s" for element "s:Envelope" is not bound."

Can you help on this

Comment: `xmlns` is not an attribute. You cannot use `<xsl:attribute>` to create them. You miss basic knowledge about XML namespaces and should take the time to read up on them. Also, please show more of your current XSLT.

Comment: Here are a couple of resources for learning about namespaces: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/ and http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm

Comment: Posting your whole XSLT would be useful, because you seem to lack essential knowledge about it.

Comment: Edited with the whole XSLT.. Please let me know is there any other approach to do convert this.

Comment: That's hardly "the whole XSLT". Please review: [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I gather some knowledge about Namespaces. At least  I have started working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, a namespace declaration is not an attribute and cannot be created by using the `xsl:attribute` instruction. In order to write the literal result elements shown in your XSLT snippet, you would need to change the code from:

```
<s:Envelope>
<xsl:attribute name="xmlns:s"><xsl:value-of select="xmlns:soapenv"/></xsl:attribute>
<s:Body>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

to:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Note that the declaration is in-scope for all descendants of the node that contains it (so there is no need to repeat it for the `s:Body` element). Most often you would include all your namespace declarations within the top-level `xsl:stylesheet` tag.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k Thanks for your reply. I have redesigned the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483583/multi-level-and-multiple-namespace-in-xml-using-xslt. Can you please help me on that.