# Multi level and multiple namespace in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new in XSLT. I need to crate a XML like this.

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Body>
        <GetRecordResponse xmlns="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService">
          <GetRecordResult xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I am able to produce the xml upto this lavel. but as there is multi lavel namespace is used I got confused.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <s:Body>
                <GetRecordResponse xmlns="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService"/>
            </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
```

I am using this XSLT for the same

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
      version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:template match = "/" > 
         <s:Envelope > 
           <s:Body>
            <xsl:element name = "GetRecordResponse" namespace = "urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService" > 
            </xsl:element> 
            </s:Body>
          </s:Envelope>             
       </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add these namespace nodes, you can use `xsl:namespace`. This is only available in processors supporting XSLT2.0 though.

```
<xsl:element name="GetRecordResponse" namespace="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService"> 
    <xsl:element name="GetRecordResult" namespace="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService">
        <xsl:namespace name="a" select="'urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core'" />
        <xsl:namespace name="i" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

Alternatively, you can probably just write out the element names and there namespace declarations literally

```
<GetRecordResponse xmlns="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService" > 
    <GetRecordResult xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
</GetRecordResponse>
```

Note that if you move the creation of `GetRecordResult` to a different template, for example, you might need to specify the default namespace on it, as it will no longer inherit the default namespce from `GetRecordResponse`

```
 <GetRecordResult xmlns="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Services.SearchService"  
    xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core" 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

Comment: The first Option does not work it give a blank element with GetRecordResult. Using the second choice I an getting a blank xmlns="". Like this

<GetRecordResult xmlns="" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="urn:RedIron.RetailRepository.Core"/>

Comment: See it in action as http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Er. The first option requires an XSLT 2.0 processor to work, as `xsl:namespace` is not available in XSLT 1.0. The second option should not result in an xmlns="", not unless you have moved the code to a different template and it no longer inherits the default namespace from "GetRecordResponse". See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. It works perfect. I think I need to learn more about xslt. can you please suggest me any.

Comment: This page on StackOverflow has links to some tutorials and books.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511759/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-xslt-files/3512184#3512184